# SQL error: "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format

I receive the error in the header when I run this case when statement in my query. Normally this error should be resulted from missing to_date function but I believe I have everything needed, but don't know why I am receiving this really. Any help is much appreciated!

```
case when week=to_date('25/06/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 26
     when week=to_date('02/07/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 27
     when week=to_date('09/07/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 28
     when week=to_date('16/07/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 29
     when week=to_date('23/07/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 30
     when week=to_date('30/07/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 31
     when week=to_date('06/08/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 32
     when week=to_date('13/08/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 33
     when week=to_date('20/08/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 34
     when week=to_date('27/08/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 35
     when week=to_date('03/09/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 36
     when week=to_date('10/09/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 37
     when week=to_date('17/09/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 38
     when week=to_date('24/09/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 39
     when week=to_date('01/10/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 40
     when week=to_date('08/10/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 41
     when week=to_date('15/10/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 42
     when week=to_date('22/10/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 43
     when week=to_date('29/10/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 44
     when week=to_date('05/11/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 45
     when week=to_date('12/11/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 46
     when week=to_date('19/11/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 47
     when week=to_date('26/11/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 48
     when week=to_date('03/12/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 49
     when week=to_date('10/12/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 50
     when week=to_date('17/12/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 51
     when week=to_date('24/12/2017','YYYY/MM/DD') then 52
    else 0 end as week,
```

Comment: you need to know that `YYYY/MM/DD` means "year/month/day". Now check the format you are giving your dates

Comment: Thanks Lamak, yes I put the format in the wrong direction!. I should have been more careful before posting here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding so many times, you can use TO_CHAR function to extract Week of the year from a given date.

In your case you can use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(week,'WW') from table_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Çağdaş, make your format like this :

> `to_date('25/06/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')`

instead of `to_date('25/06/2017','YYYY/MM/DD')` and so on like this for the others. Since the order in date formatting is wrong.

Comment: @CagdasKanar estafirullah ne demek :)

Answer (score 2):

The format is wrong.
You can use `to_date('25/06/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')` in all the expressions.